# Hundreds of the same IP Address in survey

Tags: ip, whois

In my business we have surveys about corporations (kinda like yelp).

When we looked at the IP Addresses of those who voted, there where several hundred from the same 4 IP Addresses.

I looked those up on a "whois" service and they were all registered to the company that was being voted on. That's just them voting themselfs up basically or am I crazy?

Comment: It's likely true

Comment: could there be other explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users in corporations typically wont have unique IP addresses, they will share a public IP address by using a system known as Network Address Translation - just google it for more details.

The fact you are seeing four IP addresses just mean that company uses multiple IP addresses, maybe due to different physical locations

Comment: You do not need to be in corporations. Having a smartphone and browsing from there means most of the time going through some phone provide CGN and hence sharing an IP with many other owners of a smartphone with the same provider.

Answer (score 0):

If that company have more then 1 branch, then its clear each branch have lot of users in it,each branch have one public IP with ISP and people are voting under that 4 Public IPs as you can only see public IPs not there LAN IPs.

Lets say they have 4 branches

1) 4 Branches have 4 Public IPs register under that company via ISP.

2) people start voting under that 4 Public IPs and you can only see several hundreds votes under 4 IPs address.